# angularjs not displaying all posts

Tags: loop, jquery, javascript

I learned about angularjs today and I am trying to create a page for my search results so that I can be able to create facet filters. Currently I have a page template with the following code --

```
<?php
/* Template Name:Search Results */ ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="<?php $url_info = parse_url( home_url() ); echo trailingslashit( $url_info['path'] ); ?>">
        <title>Search</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page" ng-app="app">
        <header>
            <h1>
                <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">Search</a>
            </h1>
        </header>

        <div ng-view></div>

        <footer>
            &copy; <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

As of now Im running into a problem where it is only showing me 5 posts when there is 10 in total. This is my script -

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/search-results', {
        templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'main.html',
        controller: 'Main'
    })
    .when('/:ID', {
        templateUrl: myLocalized.partials + 'content.html',
        controller: 'Content'
    });
})
.controller('Main', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/posts?type=property').success(function(res){
        $scope.posts = res;
    });
})
.controller('Content', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/posts?type=property?filter["posts_per_page"]=25&filter["orderby"]=date&filter["order"]=desc/' + $routeParams.ID).success(function(res){
        $scope.post = res;
    });
});
```

This is my partial -

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <a href="{{post.ID}}">
            {{post.title}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="post in data.posts">
        <a href="blog/{{post.id}}" ng-bind-html="post.title.rendered"></a>
        <a href="blog/{{post.id}}" ng-if="post.featured_image_thumbnail_url"><img ng-src="{{post.featured_image_thumbnail_url}}" alt="{{post.featured_image.title.rendered}}" /></a>
        <div ng-bind-html="post.excerpt.rendered"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong thats making it only show half the posts?

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
.controller('Content', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/posts?type=property?filter["posts_per_page"]=25&filter["orderby"]=date&filter["order"]=desc/' + $routeParams.ID).success(function(res){
        $scope.post = res;
```

**to this:**

```
.controller('Content', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('wp-json/posts?type=property?filter["posts_per_page"]=25&filter["orderby"]=date&filter["order"]=desc/' + $routeParams.ID).success(function(res){
        $scope.posts = res;
```

Comment: I dont see the difference ?

Comment: you missed S @ $scope.post=res;

Comment: thanks but it still doesnt show all the posts.